# How to get List<T> full dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I would like to build a little function that return `List<T>` dynamic.

Here is what I have so far.

```
   public List<T> GetLookupList<T>()
    {
        PersonalLinksEntities dbContext = new PersonalLinksEntities();

        var resultList = dbContext.????

        return resultList.toList();
    }
```

What should I do to the dbContext here?

Thanks a lot everyone!

**REPHRASE**

Here is what I have done.

Step 1: Add New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model, auto generated the objects.
Step 2: Created the no-working function above.

Comment: what does it mean to "return List<T> dynamic" ?

Comment: I think you are after making this function `generic` and not `dynamic`?

Comment: I am using EntityFramework 4.1 and I am also using Database first model. So the PersonalLinksEntities is just auto generated.

Comment: um... I guess I used the wrong work. So how do I get it generic?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to return a list of dynamic objects, or do you just want to treat your PersonalLinksEntities object as a dynamic object?

Comment: @user361022 - If you are trying to make a generic method, there's no easy way to pass in a type and return the collection on your context of that type (unless you want to dive into reflection, which is overkill for what you're trying to do here).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Just return `List<dynamic>`. No need for the generic T parameter. You might also need to cast your collection to dynamic using something like `collection.Cast<dynamic>()`.</strike>

**EDIT**
After your rephrase, I still don't know that I completely understand your question. If you are trying to pass in a type and get the collection from your context of that type, you'd be better off just implementing this code in your base classes. You would need to do reflection to do that, which is not worth the hit in performance or code clarity to save a few lines.

Comment: I guess I have to use reflection in this case... I thought it could be a very simple task, just like Nhibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ToList()` implementation to  `PersonalLinksEntities`

```
public class PersonalLinksEntities<T>
{
   ... 

   public List<T> ToList()
   {
      //construct List here and return
   }
}
```

and after

```
public List<T> GetLookupList<T>()
{
        PersonalLinksEntities dbContext = new PersonalLinksEntities();
        return dbContext .ToList<T>();

}
```

Comment: PersonalLinkEntities is a data context, not a collection. This wouldn't work.

Comment: Not very clear from the answer description/code. The variable name is irrelevant.